# Posets as (0,1)-categories

Tags: higher-category-theory, intuition, posets, enriched-category-theory

I am reading [on the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/partial+order#in_higher_category_theory) that a poset can be seen as a (0,1)-category.

I was assuming all along that an ($n$,$r$)-category were a category where all morphisms of order larger than $n$ are trivial. So that if $r>n$, a 
($n$,$r$)-category is just the same as an $n$-category.

Where am I wrong? Or are "trivial" morphisms not in general invertible?

Some extra intuition on how that exactly works in the poset case would also be very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: The definition at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28n%2Cr%29-category explains it: in an (n,r) category, any parallel j-arrows are equivalent, when j>n.

Comment: Also the meaning you ascribe / assume is not quite that in the n-lab:  "An (n,1)-category is an (∞,1)-category such that every hom ∞-groupoid is (n-1)-truncated" so $n=0$ is feasible.

Comment: Oh I see. I was just imaging it shifted of one below, my bad!